# Counting matches from preg_match_all

Tags: php, count, preg-match, preg-match-all

I've been searching for similar question but haven't found no one with similar problem or possible solution.
I have  preg_match_all function which finds me 5 matches and returns them in array. How can I count strings that are in array ?

```
preg_match_all("/\)\">(.*?)<\/a>/s",$value,$counter);
here is var_dump(counter[1]):
array (size=1)


0 => string 'word1' (length=..)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'word2' (length=..)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'word3' (length=..)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'word4' (length=..)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'word5' (length=..)
```

As you seen it returns me 5 matches, but i cant print that number neither with `array_count_values`, `count()`... I've tried imploding then to get strings but `count()` wont work either.

```
    count($counter[1]) returns me ->
int 1

int 1

int 1

int 1

int 1
```

I need to get number of matches and I dont have any more ideas, so anything is very welcome.

Update: Here is var_dump($value);

`string '<h2><a href="javascript:Organigram.toggle('organigram_section_29')">word1</a></h2><div class="show"><p class="nums"><span class="phone">03 839 11 00</span></p>' (length=170)`

`string '<h2><a href="javascript:Organigram.toggle('organigram_section_35')">word2</a></h2><div class="show"><p class="nums"><span class="phone">03 839 12 00</span><span class="fax">03 839 12 18</span><span class="email email-mod"><a title="info@golte.si" href="mailto:info@golte.si"><img alt='info@golte.si' src='Txt2Image.ashx?AAARAAcASQAAAB0AEgAGADMAEwAGAB8AAAAMAF0ABwAAAFUAGQAGABcAEQBUAAAAAAAQAB8AEQANAFUAEgAGAB0AAABUADIABgAAABIAGABSAEIAQABSAAMADABSAFAARQAtAEcARQBeADYATwALABwAGAANAEMARABZAEMARQBdADIARQA=' /></a></s'`... (length=938)`

`string '<h2><a href="javascript:Organigram.toggle('organigram_section_51')">word3</a></h2><div class="show"><p class="nums"><span class="phone">03 839 12 12</span></p>' (length=162)`

`string '<h2><a href="javascript:Organigram.toggle('organigram_section_56')">word4</a></h2><div class="show"><p class="nums"><span class="phone">03 839 12 14</span></p>' (length=168)`

`string '<h2><a href="javascript:Organigram.toggle('organigram_section_61')">word5</a></h2><div class="show"><p class="nums"><span class="phone">03 839 61 28</span></p>' (length=162)`

Comment: use count() function to get the array count

Answer (score 7, accepted):

preg_match_all itself returns the number of full pattern matches (which might be zero), or FALSE if an error occurred.

```
$number = preg_match_all("/\)\">(.*?)<\/a>/s",$value,$counter);
```

Comment: It ruturns the total number of matches. If it is returning 1 then it means that, there is only 1 match for your pattern.

Comment: $numRows2 = var_dump($counter[1]);
-->
    array (size=1)
  0 => string 'sale' (length=4)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'manage' (length=6)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'cash' (length=4)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'accounts' (length=8)

array (size=1)
  0 => string 'director' (length=8)

Comment: Can you paste bin the contents of $value?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

/* function strlen1($val)
{
    return strlen($val);
} */

//get the each value count
$b = array_map('strlen', $counter);

print_r($b);
```